# Does a kill within 10 seconds of a Twisted Fate ultimate give him an assist?

Tags: league-of-legends

An assist is scored "by hitting the champion in the last 10 seconds before his death, or by contributing passively during this period of time." Now I know that things like placing a shield or a heal on someone else that hit the champion will result in an assist, but does the vision granted by his ultimate or any other vision given by an ability such as Ashe's Hawkshot give an assist?

Answer (score 5):

No, granting vision through a skill such as Ashe's Hawkshot or Twisted Fate's ultimate does not give you an assist.

Edit: Proven

Comment: Do you have any proof for that? Because Twisted Fate's ultimate places a debuff on his enemies which may work different than Ashe's Hawkshot.

Comment: I do not, but I will test is later today when I wake up. Going to bed now...all nighter un-success!

Comment: TF Ult does NOT give an assist. Played him today, fed like a boss and got no assists from simply using ult. ):

Answer (score 3):

I know **it doesn't**. Basicly because I've played Twisted Fate a lot of times and gotten annoyed by the fact that my ulti on that hidden Akali didn't give me an assist.

I understand why you think it should, but at the same time it would give him silly much assists at ganks if he "tagged" 5 heroes at a fight. Apart from that, I upgrade TF in Utility mastery, meaning that I'd get a lot of experience through all assists, basicly by doing nothing.

The reason to my beliefs why Twisted Fate doesn't get assist are these conditions:

- It doesn't neccessary help the kill. People can die being fully visible regardless.
- It's easy to add. Sure, Sorakas ulti is also easy to add, but it got longer cooldown and affects directly a situation in combat (in theory)
- You can decrease it's cooldown so much that allowing people to "tag" with that ulti often leads to many unjustified assists
- Riot probably don't want Twisted Fates to pop his ulti *JUST* to get assists, without even needing to use the teleport part of the ulti
- He already got his AoE cards to tag enemies. They are sufficient enough.

So basicly even if he attaches a debuff to the enemies, Riot made sure it didn't let him to get assists just because of it.

By **tag**, I mean officially helping to kill an enemy.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't for the same reason they removed assists from Nocturne's ultimate, it used to give assists just for the darkness but this means he gets free assists and gold every teamfight even if he does nothing.